# Exception Handling:Display Exception Message through Main Method

Tags: c#

I have three methods (including `Main`) where exception handling is done for each. Now I want to print the exception messages of other methods through `Main`.

**Note:** I want to use only one `Console.WriteLine()` and have it be in `Main`.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Arthimatic(10, 0));
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message " + ex.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    private static int? Arthimatic(int num1, int num2)
    {
        try
        {
            int? value = Divide(num1, num2);
            return value;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return null; }
    }
    private static int? Divide(int num1, int num2)
    {
        try
        {
            int num3 = (num1 / num2);
            return num3;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return null; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you dividing by 0?

Comment: Your life will be much better if you remove **all** of the `catch (Exception ex)` exception blocks. You should use minimal exception handling, and only ever catch specific exceptions (i.e. `DivideByZeroException` rather than `Exception`) and only ever handle exceptions that you can meaningfully handle.

Comment: `Divide` should be the only one that needs to catch the `DivideByZeroException`. It's not throwing anyother exception, so there's nothing for `Arthimatic` to catch, and nothing for `Main` either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then just re-throw the same exception in your other method like below. Moreover, you don't need a `try..catch` handling on every method since your main calling method handles exception; if in the called method exception occurs it will bubble up to `Main()` where it will get caught up

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your life will be much better if you remove all of the `catch (Exception ex)` exception blocks. You should use minimal exception handling, and only ever catch specific exceptions (i.e. `DivideByZeroException`rather` than Exception) and only ever handle exceptions that you can meaningfully handle.

Your code should really look something like one of these two choices:

(1)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Arthimatic(10, 0));
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" Message " + ex.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

private static int Arthimatic(int num1, int num2)
{
    return Divide(num1, num2);
}

private static int Divide(int num1, int num2)
{
    return num1 / num2;
}
```

(2)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (Arthimatic(10, 0) == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An Error Occurred.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}

private static int? Arthimatic(int num1, int num2)
{
    return Divide(num1, num2);
}

private static int? Divide(int num1, int num2)
{
    try
    {
        return num1 / num2;
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```